# Failed to load asmx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, asmx

I am using the gleamtech filevistacontrol for a back-end of a website. When i load the page which contains the control i get an error that a language file could not be found.

I get an 404 response when calling the webservice. The application is running on a windows server 2008. On my development machine the application is running without problems. I got the filevista control running in another application but this is running on a windows server 2003 machine.

Things i have tried:
1. Verified all that all files are there and that the permissions are set correctly

2. I added the following line in my web.config in the system.web section.

   ```
   <webServices>
       <protocols>
           <add name="HttpPost"/>
       </protocols>
   </webServices>
   ```
3. I started from scratch with deploying the application
4. I tried two different versions of the filevistacontrol

My guess is that is has something to do with the asmx that couldn't be loaded but i am out of options..

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it solved. The handler mapping configuration in IIS 7.5 was wrong... the mapping for *.asmx was set to local. Right click --> Revert to parent solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in your web.config:

```
<add name="aspnet_isapi 32-bit" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" 
scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" 
preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
```